# Very slow scrolling/zooming experience with GMUClusterRenderer (Google Maps Clustering) on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, hierarchical-clustering

I will try to explain my issue, and what I have done so far.

**Introduction:**

I am using the [iOS Utils Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) from Google Maps in order to display around 300 markers on the map.

The algorithm used for the Clustering is the `GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm`.

Basically, our users can send us the weather they observe *through their window*, so that we can display the real time weather around the world.

It enables us to improve and/or adjust the weather forecasts.

But my scrolling/zooming experience isn't smooth at all. By the way I am testing it with an iPhone X ...

**Let's get to the heart of the matter:**

Here is how I configure the `ClusterManager`

```
private func configureCluster(array: [Observation]) -> Void {

     let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
     let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
     let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView,
                                            clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
     renderer.delegate = self
     clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm,
                                           renderer: renderer)
     clusterManager.add(array)
     clusterManager.cluster()
     clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
}
```

Here is my `Observation` class, I tried to keep it simple :

```
class Observation : NSObject, GMUClusterItem {

    static var ICON_SIZE = 30

    let timestamp: Double
    let idObs: String
    let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let idPicto: [Int]
    let token: String
    let comment: String
    let altitude: Double

    init(timestamp: Double, idObs: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, idPicto: [Int], token: String, comment: String, altitude: Double) {

        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.idObs = idObs
        self.position = coordinate
        self.idPicto = idPicto
        self.token = token
        self.comment = comment
        self.altitude = altitude
    }
}
```

And finally, the delegate method for the rendering :

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {

        if let cluster = marker.userData as? GMUCluster {
            if let listObs = cluster.items as? [Observation] {
                if listObs.count > 1 {
                    let sortedObs = listObs.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp })
                    if let mostRecentObs = sortedObs.first {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.setIconViewForMarker(marker: marker, obs: mostRecentObs)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if let obs = listObs.last {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.setIconViewForMarker(marker: marker, obs: obs)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Users can only send one observation, but this observation can be composed with various weather phenomenoms (like Clouds + Rain + Wind) or only Rain if they want.

To differenciate them, if it's only 1 phenomenom, the `marker.iconView` property will be set directly.

On the other hand, if it's an observation with multiple phenomenoms, I will create a View containing all the images representing the phenomenoms.

```
func setIconViewForMarker(marker: GMSMarker, obs: Observation) -> Void {

        let isYourObs = Observation.isOwnObservation(id: obs.idObs) ? true : false

        if isYourObs {
           marker.iconView = Observation.viewForPhenomenomArray(ids: obs.idPicto, isYourObs: isYourObs)
        } else {
            // Observation with more than 1 phenomenom
            if obs.idPicto.count > 1 {
                marker.iconView = Observation.viewForPhenomenomArray(ids: obs.idPicto, isYourObs: isYourObs)

                // Observation with only 1 phenomenom
            } else if obs.idPicto.count == 1 {
                if let id = obs.idPicto.last {
                    marker.iconView = Observation.setImageForPhenomenom(id: id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the last piece of code, to show you how I build this custom view (I think my issue is probably here)

```
class func viewForPhenomenomArray(ids: [Int], isYourObs: Bool) -> UIView {

        let popupView = UIView()

        popupView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: (ICON_SIZE * ids.count) + ((ids.count + 1) * 5) , height: ICON_SIZE)

        if (isYourObs) {
            popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.61, blue:0.20, alpha:1)
        } else {
           popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.31, blue:0.57, alpha:1)
        }

        popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 12

        for (index, element) in ids.enumerated() {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: Observation.getPictoFromID(id: element))
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: ((index + 1) * 5) + index * ICON_SIZE, y: 0, width: ICON_SIZE, height: ICON_SIZE)
            popupView.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        return popupView
    }
```

I also tried with very small image, to understand if the issue comes from rendering a lot of PNGs on the map, but seriously, it's an iPhone X, it should be able to render some simple weather icon on a map.

Do you think I am doing something wrong ? Or is it a known issue in the Google Maps SDK ? (I have read that it is fixed at 30 fps)

Do you think rendering a lot of images (as marker.image) on a map takes that much GPU? To a point where the experience isn't acceptable at all?

If you have any advice, I'll take them all.

Comment: Just to take this out of the way, did you try it with a "release" build ? Dev builds lacks optimization and can sometimes have performance issues.

Comment: Yes I just tried it, and the difference is not mindblowing.

Comment: That's not our issue then (obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. After debugging a lot and checking google's code even, i come to the conclusion that, issue was from `GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator`. This class is creating images at runtime for given cluster size that you are displaying. So, when you zoom in or zoom out the map, the cluster size is going to update, and this class creates new image for new number(Even it keep images cached, if same number get repeated).

So, the solution that i found is to use `buckets`. You will get surprised by seeing this new term. Let me explain the bucket concept by giving simple example.

suppose you kept bucket sizes as 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000.

- Now, if your cluster is 3, then it will show 3.
- If cluster size = 8, show = 8.
- If cluster size = 16, show = 10+.
- If cluster size = 22, show = 20+.
- If cluster size = 48, show = 20+.
- If cluster size = 91, show = 50+.
- If cluster size = 177, show = 100+.
- If cluster size = 502, show = 500+.
- If cluster size = 1200004, show = 1000+.

Now here, for any cluster size, the marker images that are going to be rendered will be from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10+, 20+, 50+, 100+, 200+, 500+, 1000+. As it caches the images, so this images is going to be reused. So, the time+cpu that it was using for creating new images is lowered(only few images required to be created).

You must have got the idea, about buckets now. As, if cluster is having very small number, then cluster size matters, but if increases, then bucket size is enough to get idea about cluster size.

Now, question is how to achieve this.

Actually, `GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator` class has already this functionality implemented, you just need to change its initialisation to this:

```
let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator(buckets: [ 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000])
```

`GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator` class have other init methods, by using which you can give different background colors to different buckets, different background images to to different buckets and many more.

Let me know, if any further help required.

Comment: Ok I understand your point. I just found the issue thanks to your answer. The slow experience came from that for each cluster, I was calculating which image to display for the marker (let sortedObs = listObs.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp })). I am displaying the most recent observation each time. Which mean this calculation was made every zoom. Moreover, my PNG Images were not at the proper size. Get the most recent item + Resize PNG image * 300 times = slow experience. Thank you